# What is the best way to re-serve day old meat balls?

Tags: culinary-uses, reheating, meatballs

I've noticed that meatballs are one type of food that often tastes much better the next day.  So whenever I make meatballs, I make lots of extras and put them in my fridge to allow the flavors to "develop".

However, when I warm the meatballs up in the microwave they sometimes get dry or have slightly tough and rubbery spots -- especially on outside edges.

What is the best technique to re-warm / re-serve meatballs that you have made the previous day (or a couple days prior) so they stay moist and delicious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My preferred method by far would be heating them in a pot along with some kind of sauce.

Failing that, I think I might try putting them in a tightly covered pot in the oven along with just a little water (just a tablespoon or so)--that would gently heat them and also keep them moist.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, instead of using the microwave put them in the pot with the sauce that you made and add a bit of extra water. Carefully move them around so they get warmed up evenly and do not lose shape.

You can achieve similar results by putting all together in the microwave for half the time, then toss them around, and put them in for the rest of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Microwave method-  Use a defrost setting like #2 instead of #10 full power, every microwave is different, I also reheat steak and Prime rib this way and it is excellent, be patient and it will turn out nicely.  P.s I am in the Restaurant biz..

Stove Top- Reheat in the sauce if you have it on low, if not reheat in a light beef bouillon water on low or about 140 degrees.

Oven-   place into oven on sheet pan with a splash of water cover with saran wrap, heat
        at 225 degrees for 25 minutes or so.

Answer (score -2):

I can't yet add to this, however my meatballs are gourmet and any tomato based sauce would lower their standing.

What I'm thinking, even though I have not done this yet, is to reserve the grease left over from cooking them and reheating with that, probably in the oven.

Up to this point I have reheated in the microwave.  At work they do this as well, but then the meatballs sit in sauce in the steam table all day long.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think you meant this to be a comment on bikeboy's answer. If your technique of reheating with grease does turn out to work, that'd be welcome as a standalone answer, though.

Comment: We tend to frown on hypothetical/speculative answers here; people who ask/search for questions are looking for tried and tested solutions, or at a minimum, solutions grounded in clear and undisputed theory. Please revise your answer when you have something more concrete - otherwise it will probably continue to accrue downvotes.

Comment: "my meatballs are gourmet and any tomato based sauce would lower their standing" REALLY?? LOL!  -1